# NestJS issues setting/generating migration paths with TypeORM

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I've been following the NestJS and TypeORM documentation. Now I'm at a point where I should start generating migrations. The migration itself seem to be generating the correct queries. However they are not generating where I want them to.

Currently I'm using this in my `package.json`:

`"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -d src/datasource src/migrations/"`

This command came from an issue I found on github. The original was:

`"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -d src/datasource src/migrations/$npm_config_name"`

The original command puts it in the `migrations` folder but names it `{timestamp}-$npm_config_name`. When i remove the `config_name` part the migration goes into the source folder with the name `{timestamp}-migrations`.

I've looked up countless of github issues but most seemed to be for version 0.3.12 and I'm using 0.3.17.

Is there any way how I can make it so i can simply use this command as: `npm run migration:generate {name}`?

For those wondering this is my datasource file:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const PostgresDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: '...',
  port: 5432,
  username: '...',
  password: '...',
  database: '...',

  entities: ['src/entities/*.entity.ts'],
  migrations: ['src/migrations/*.ts'],
});

PostgresDataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Datasource init');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error during Data Source initialization', err);
  });
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new npm script in your package.json file to do the job.

Example:

```
"migration:generate": "typeorm-ts-node-esm migration:generate -d src/db/migration.configuration.ts src/db/migrations/$npm_config_name",
```

NOTE: make sure to change the path(s) in the passed-in args

1st argument (src/db/migration.configuration.ts): define your datasource configuration file destination

2nd argument (src/db/migrations/$npm_config_name"): new migration file destination with dynamic placeholder for the file name

You can than generate a new migration script by hitting the command in terminal: `npm run migration:generate --name={NAME}` and the output migration file will have the format you are looking for `TIMESTAMP-{name}`

Comment: I just tried this and it's giving me the unknown arguments, I've been using this `npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -d src/datasource.ts src/migrations/{name}` and change the name every time now

Comment: Ah, my bad, I forgot to add this 'name' flag for the terminal command, so it looks like this
`npm run migration:generate --name={NAME}`
I will edit the answer as well for visibility

Comment: I'll be back in a bit and will try it out, appreciate your effort!